# I don't get what doesn't work when i try to do these codepen's liquid button

Tags: javascript, button

I try to re-do these lovely liquid buttons visible here on codepen: https://codepen.io/architechnium/pen/wpYgGY
I try to do it on local webpage files, but what is weird is that there is nothing which appears on my local web file. Even if i download the zip files directly from code pen it doesn't work locally.
And it's the same on the stack overflow's editor as you can see it below, the page stays totally white and there are some message error. Does anybody could help me to make it work on my local files or on the stackoverflow's editor ?

Thank you very much, it would be awesome.

```js
var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)){break;} var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); }
window.CP.exitedLoop(1);
 } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var LiquidButton = function () {
  function LiquidButton(svg) {
    _classCallCheck(this, LiquidButton);

    var options = svg.dataset;
    this.id = this.constructor.id || (this.constructor.id = 1);
    this.constructor.id++;
    this.xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
    this.tension = options.tension * 1 || 0.4;
    this.width = options.width * 1 || 200;
    this.height = options.height * 1 || 50;
    this.margin = options.margin || 50;
    this.hoverFactor = options.hoverFactor || -0.1;
    this.gap = options.gap || 5;
    this.debug = options.debug || false;
    this.forceFactor = options.forceFactor || 0.2;
    this.color1 = options.color1 || '#36DFE7';
    this.color2 = options.color2 || '#8F17E1';
    this.color3 = options.color3 || '#BF09E6';
    this.textColor = options.textColor || '#FFFFFF';
    this.text = options.text || '▶';
    this.svg = svg;
    this.layers = [{
      points: [],
      viscosity: 0.5,
      mouseForce: 100,
      forceLimit: 2
    }, {
      points: [],
      viscosity: 0.8,
      mouseForce: 150,
      forceLimit: 3
    }];
    for (var layerIndex = 0; layerIndex < this.layers.length; layerIndex++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(2)){break;}
      var layer = this.layers[layerIndex];
      layer.viscosity = options['layer-' + (layerIndex + 1) + 'Viscosity'] * 1 || layer.viscosity;
      layer.mouseForce = options['layer-' + (layerIndex + 1) + 'MouseForce'] * 1 || layer.mouseForce;
      layer.forceLimit = options['layer-' + (layerIndex + 1) + 'ForceLimit'] * 1 || layer.forceLimit;
      layer.path = document.createElementNS(this.xmlns, 'path');
      this.svg.appendChild(layer.path);
    }
window.CP.exitedLoop(2);

    this.wrapperElement = options.wrapperElement || document.body;
    if (!this.svg.parentElement) {
      this.wrapperElement.append(this.svg);
    }

    this.svgText = document.createElementNS(this.xmlns, 'text');
    this.svgText.setAttribute('x', '50%');
    this.svgText.setAttribute('y', '50%');
    this.svgText.setAttribute('dy', ~~(this.height / 8) + 'px');
    this.svgText.setAttribute('font-size', ~~(this.height / 3));
    this.svgText.style.fontFamily = 'sans-serif';
    this.svgText.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'middle');
    this.svgText.setAttribute('pointer-events', 'none');
    this.svg.appendChild(this.svgText);

    this.svgDefs = document.createElementNS(this.xmlns, 'defs');
    this.svg.appendChild(this.svgDefs);

    this.touches = [];
    this.noise = options.noise || 0;
    document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', this.touchHandler);
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', this.touchHandler);
    document.body.addEventListener('touchend', this.clearHandler);
    document.body.addEventListener('touchcancel', this.clearHandler);
    this.svg.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseHandler);
    this.svg.addEventListener('mouseout', this.clearHandler);
    this.initOrigins();
    this.animate();
  }

  _createClass(LiquidButton, [{
    key: 'distance',
    value: function distance(p1, p2) {
      return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
    }
  }, {
    key: 'update',
    value: function update() {
      for (var layerIndex = 0; layerIndex < this.layers.length; layerIndex++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(6)){break;}
        var layer = this.layers[layerIndex];
        var points = layer.points;
        for (var pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < points.length; pointIndex++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(4)){break;}
          var point = points[pointIndex];
          var dx = point.ox - point.x + (Math.random() - 0.5) * this.noise;
          var dy = point.oy - point.y + (Math.random() - 0.5) * this.noise;
          var d = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
          var f = d * this.forceFactor;
          point.vx += f * (dx / d || 0);
          point.vy += f * (dy / d || 0);
          for (var touchIndex = 0; touchIndex < this.touches.length; touchIndex++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(3)){break;}
            var touch = this.touches[touchIndex];
            var mouseForce = layer.mouseForce;
            if (touch.x > this.margin && touch.x < this.margin + this.width && touch.y > this.margin && touch.y < this.margin + this.height) {
              mouseForce *= -this.hoverFactor;
            }
            var mx = point.x - touch.x;
            var my = point.y - touch.y;
            var md = Math.sqrt(mx * mx + my * my);
            var mf = Math.max(-layer.forceLimit, Math.min(layer.forceLimit, mouseForce * touch.force / md));
            point.vx += mf * (mx / md || 0);
            point.vy += mf * (my / md || 0);
          }
window.CP.exitedLoop(3);

          point.vx *= layer.viscosity;
          point.vy *= layer.viscosity;
          point.x += point.vx;
          point.y += point.vy;
        }
window.CP.exitedLoop(4);

        for (var _pointIndex = 0; _pointIndex < points.length; _pointIndex++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(5)){break;}
          var prev = points[(_pointIndex + points.length - 1) % points.length];
          var _point = points[_pointIndex];
          var next = points[(_pointIndex + points.length + 1) % points.length];
          var dPrev = this.distance(_point, prev);
          var dNext = this.distance(_point, next);

          var line = {
            x: next.x - prev.x,
            y: next.y - prev.y
          };
          var dLine = Math.sqrt(line.x * line.x + line.y * line.y);

          _point.cPrev = {
            x: _point.x - line.x / dLine * dPrev * this.tension,
            y: _point.y - line.y / dLine * dPrev * this.tension
          };
          _point.cNext = {
            x: _point.x + line.x / dLine * dNext * this.tension,
            y: _point.y + line.y / dLine * dNext * this.tension
          };
        }
window.CP.exitedLoop(5);

      }
window.CP.exitedLoop(6);

    }
  }, {
    key: 'animate',
    value: function animate() {
      var _this = this;

      this.raf(function () {
        _this.update();
        _this.draw();
        _this.animate();
      });
    }
  }, {
    key: 'draw',
    value: function draw() {
      for (var layerIndex = 0; layerIndex < this.layers.length; layerIndex++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(10)){break;}
        var layer = this.layers[layerIndex];
        if (layerIndex === 1) {
          if (this.touches.length > 0) {
            while (this.svgDefs.firstChild) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(7)){break;}
              this.svgDefs.removeChild(this.svgDefs.firstChild);
            }
window.CP.exitedLoop(7);

            for (var touchIndex = 0; touchIndex < this.touches.length; touchIndex++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(8)){break;}
              var touch = this.touches[touchIndex];
              var gradient = document.createElementNS(this.xmlns, 'radialGradient');
              gradient.id = 'liquid-gradient-' + this.id + '-' + touchIndex;
              var start = document.createElementNS(this.xmlns, 'stop');
              start.setAttribute('stop-color', this.color3);
              start.setAttribute('offset', '0%');
              var stop = document.createElementNS(this.xmlns, 'stop');
              stop.setAttribute('stop-color', this.color2);
              stop.setAttribute('offset', '100%');
              gradient.appendChild(start);
              gradient.appendChild(stop);
              this.svgDefs.appendChild(gradient);
              gradient.setAttribute('cx', touch.x / this.svgWidth);
              gradient.setAttribute('cy', touch.y / this.svgHeight);
              gradient.setAttribute('r', touch.force);
              layer.path.style.fill = 'url(#' + gradient.id + ')';
            }
window.CP.exitedLoop(8);

          } else {
            layer.path.style.fill = this.color2;
          }
        } else {
          layer.path.style.fill = this.color1;
        }
        var points = layer.points;
        var commands = [];
        commands.push('M', points[0].x, points[0].y);
        for (var pointIndex = 1; pointIndex < points.length; pointIndex += 1) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(9)){break;}
          commands.push('C', points[(pointIndex + 0) % points.length].cNext.x, points[(pointIndex + 0) % points.length].cNext.y, points[(pointIndex + 1) % points.length].cPrev.x, points[(pointIndex + 1) % points.length].cPrev.y, points[(pointIndex + 1) % points.length].x, points[(pointIndex + 1) % points.length].y);
        }
window.CP.exitedLoop(9);

        commands.push('Z');
        layer.path.setAttribute('d', commands.join(' '));
      }
window.CP.exitedLoop(10);

      this.svgText.textContent = this.text;
      this.svgText.style.fill = this.textColor;
    }
  }, {
    key: 'createPoint',
    value: function createPoint(x, y) {
      return {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        ox: x,
        oy: y,
        vx: 0,
        vy: 0
      };
    }
  }, {
    key: 'initOrigins',
    value: function initOrigins() {
      this.svg.setAttribute('width', this.svgWidth);
      this.svg.setAttribute('height', this.svgHeight);
      for (var layerIndex = 0; layerIndex < this.layers.length; layerIndex++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(15)){break;}
        var layer = this.layers[layerIndex];
        var points = [];
        for (var x = ~~(this.height / 2); x < this.width - ~~(this.height / 2); x += this.gap) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(11)){break;}
          points.push(this.createPoint(x + this.margin, this.margin));
        }
window.CP.exitedLoop(11);

        for (var alpha = ~~(this.height * 1.25); alpha >= 0; alpha -= this.gap) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(12)){break;}
          var angle = Math.PI / ~~(this.height * 1.25) * alpha;
          points.push(this.createPoint(Math.sin(angle) * this.height / 2 + this.margin + this.width - this.height / 2, Math.cos(angle) * this.height / 2 + this.margin + this.height / 2));
        }
window.CP.exitedLoop(12);

        for (var _x = this.width - ~~(this.height / 2) - 1; _x >= ~~(this.height / 2); _x -= this.gap) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(13)){break;}
          points.push(this.createPoint(_x + this.margin, this.margin + this.height));
        }
window.CP.exitedLoop(13);

        for (var _alpha = 0; _alpha <= ~~(this.height * 1.25); _alpha += this.gap) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(14)){break;}
          var _angle = Math.PI / ~~(this.height * 1.25) * _alpha;
          points.push(this.createPoint(this.height - Math.sin(_angle) * this.height / 2 + this.margin - this.height / 2, Math.cos(_angle) * this.height / 2 + this.margin + this.height / 2));
        }
window.CP.exitedLoop(14);

        layer.points = points;
      }
window.CP.exitedLoop(15);

    }
  }, {
    key: 'mouseHandler',
    get: function get() {
      var _this2 = this;

      return function (e) {
        _this2.touches = [{
          x: e.offsetX,
          y: e.offsetY,
          force: 1
        }];
      };
    }
  }, {
    key: 'touchHandler',
    get: function get() {
      var _this3 = this;

      return function (e) {
        _this3.touches = [];
        var rect = _this3.svg.getBoundingClientRect();
        for (var touchIndex = 0; touchIndex < e.changedTouches.length; touchIndex++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(16)){break;}
          var touch = e.changedTouches[touchIndex];
          var x = touch.pageX - rect.left;
          var y = touch.pageY - rect.top;
          if (x > 0 && y > 0 && x < _this3.svgWidth && y < _this3.svgHeight) {
            _this3.touches.push({ x: x, y: y, force: touch.force || 1 });
          }
        }
window.CP.exitedLoop(16);

        e.preventDefault();
      };
    }
  }, {
    key: 'clearHandler',
    get: function get() {
      var _this4 = this;

      return function (e) {
        _this4.touches = [];
      };
    }
  }, {
    key: 'raf',
    get: function get() {
      return this.__raf || (this.__raf = (window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 10);
      }).bind(window));
    }
  }, {
    key: 'svgWidth',
    get: function get() {
      return this.width + this.margin * 2;
    }
  }, {
    key: 'svgHeight',
    get: function get() {
      return this.height + this.margin * 2;
    }
  }]);

  return LiquidButton;
}();

var redraw = function redraw() {
  button.initOrigins();
};

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('liquid-button');
for (var buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < buttons.length; buttonIndex++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(17)){break;}
  var _button = buttons[buttonIndex];
  _button.liquidButton = new LiquidButton(_button);
}
window.CP.exitedLoop(17);
```

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  user-select: none;
}

.liquid-button path {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg class="liquid-button"></svg>
<svg class="liquid-button"
  data-width="50"
  data-height="50"
  data-text="✖"
></svg>
<svg class="liquid-button"
  data-color1="#cb60b3"
  data-color2="#c146a1"
  data-color3="#db36a4"
  data-text="colored"
></svg>
<svg class="liquid-button"
  data-color1="#ccc"
  data-color2="#000"
  data-color3="#232425"
  data-text="black & white"
></svg>
<svg class="liquid-button"
  data-text="different viscosity"
  data-force-factor="0.1"
  data-layer-1-viscosity="0.5"
  data-layer-2-viscosity="0.4"
  data-layer-1-mouse-force="400"
  data-layer-2-mouse-force="500"
  data-layer-1-force-limit="1"
  data-layer-2-force-limit="2"
></svg>
<svg class="liquid-button"
  data-text="hover"
  data-hover-factor="-10"
></svg>
```

Comment: It looks like `CP` is an object attached to the `window` object in CodePen which is not available in your local browser. You will need to modify your code or use some polyfill for CP to make it work.

Comment: All right, thanks for this comment, i'll try to see what i can do with polyfill !